# Collect IDs from a text in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text document with many similar to this elements -

```
groupId="FDhur..."
```

I would like to be able to find each place there is a groupId and store the string that is between the quotes in a variable. How can I do that?

This is how I have been trying to do it so far:

```
groupId_list = [] # holds all the ids in final xml file
try:
    x = BeautifulSoup(xml.text,'html.parser')

    #pattern = re.findAll(r'groupId=(\".*?\")',x)
    # of course, we can assign the return value of findAll to groupId_list, instead and we then would not have to copy the results over later
    results = re.findAll(r'groupId="(.*?)"',x) # Booboo

    #print(pattern)
    print(results) # Booboo
    
    #if pattern is not None:
    if results:
        print("FOUND")

    #for i in pattern: # append all the product ids in this list
    for i in results: # Booboo
        #groupId_list.append(i.text)
        groupId_list.append(i) # Booboo
    return groupId_list 
except:
    return None
```

Comment: What have your attempted?

Comment: I have been trying to find it with regex, but I get no output and I am not sure how to store the matches in a variable. This is my regex - r'groupId=(\".*?\")')

Comment: Show us whatever code you have.

Comment: Ok, I just did that

Comment: 1. You don't need \ before ". 2. You don't want the " characters as part of your capture group. 3. `findAll` returns a list, which might be empty but it will never be `None`.

Comment: I have attempted to edit your code, if you don't mind, which might be a better learning expereince.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
groupId="([^"]*)"
```

1. `groupId="` Matches 'groupId"'
2. `([^"]*)` Matches 0 or more characters that are not a `"` in capture group 1
3. `"` Matches a `"`

The code:

```
import re

s = 'groupId="FDhu1" some more text and then groupId="xyz" and some more text'

results = re.findall(r'groupId="([^"]*)"', s)
print(results)
```

Prints:

```
['FDhu1', 'xyz']
```